# java simulate post form with redirect

Tags: java, servlets, post, redirect

I have an application with login form. In that application there is a servlet that can perform the login accepting username and password (post, no get parameters) and performing the login and setting a Jsession cookie.

When I call this servlet with a form post it works.

But I have another application where I want to redirect and automatically login to the first application. This will be for demo use and thus a static username and password will be used. But I don't want the users to be able to see the username and password. Therefore I want to use a post  in Java.

This works partly, after the post is done (the login is made), I redirect to a page in application 1. But then I'm not logged in anymore. 
I suppose it has something to do with the domains. Application 1 and 2 are not on the same domain.

How can I fix my problem?

Here is the code I use to perform the post request

```
getLog().debug("Open the connection to remote URL(" + remoteURL + ")");
URL url = new URL(remoteURL);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr;
wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

wr.write(requestParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
```

Comment: The login is perfomed by Application 2, not by the user.

Comment: Yes, and No :) The login in application 1 is done by application 1. But it is called from application 2 and not by the user.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. That's why the user is not logged in.

Comment: and how can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. If  you are not using JAAS for implement the security

   - Sure when you do the authentication in the App1 you are storing in the HttpSession a flag for know if the user is authenticated in order to avoid require login on further requests. So the ServletContainer manage the HttpSession automatically  sending to the Browser the session ID using different mechanisms (the most common a cookie).
   - Let imagine that the Servlet container is managing the HttpSession (Session ID) with cookies. When your App2 makes the login (and it is succesfully) you aren't storing the cookie with the Session Id for further request.
   - You need to check which is the mechanism for manage the session id and replicate the browser behavior in your App2 for further requests.
2. If you are using JAAS for implement the security. You have two options:

   - Check if your Servlet Container (or Application Server) supports programmatic login. So you can login programatically in your App2 to the same Security Realm of App1.
   - Check if Servlet Container (or Application Server) have support for SSO. This let enable to you configure both applications for use the same Security Realm and when the user logins in the App1 automatically logins too in App2. (If you do this check the behavior of logout)